# check for some special characters in folder name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I am creating folder. When a folder is created with name containing - /:*?"<>| characters , I want to do validation to show error message - "A folder name cannot contain any of the following special characters /:*?"<>| ".

What logic should i use to do the validation for folder name?

Comment: Correct set of characters that i want to validate are these  \/:*?"<>|

Comment: Consider using the `ng-pattern` directive to prevent users from entering invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`str.match(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/match) on the filename string before the creation of the folder.

Comment: Take a look on the link provide by @Pete comment